# UIScrollView content offset x gets set to 0 when scroll UITableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiscrollview, uipagecontrol

I have a UITableView with one of the UITableViewCells containing a UIScrollView and a UIPageControl; so that the user can scroll horizontally through two pages whilst browsing the table.

My problem is this- initially the page control works fine, I can see the little dots moving as expected as I browse through the pages in the scroll view. However, when I scroll the *table* up or down, the page control always resets back to the first page.

This is because my method which determines the page, uses the scrollview.contentoffset.x to work out which page I'm on, and the contentoffset.x ALWAYS returns 0 as soon as I start moving the table up or down. The actual scrollview itself physically does not move left or right (the content stays on the correct page); so I'm not sure why the contentoffset.x is always resetting to 0?

Here is my code in cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
        UIScrollView* previewScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.frame.size.width, tideRowHeight)];
        [previewScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(640, tideRowHeight)];
        [previewScrollView setPagingEnabled:YES];
        [previewScrollView setTag:0022];
        [previewScrollView setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];
        [previewScrollView setDelegate:self];

        [previewScrollView addSubview:todayTidesTime];
        [previewScrollView addSubview:todayTidesHeight];
        [previewScrollView addSubview:todayTidesHL];

        [[cell contentView] addSubview:previewScrollView];


        UIPageControl *tidesPageControl = [[UIPageControl alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 130, cell.frame.size.width, 10)];
        [tidesPageControl setNumberOfPages:2];
        [tidesPageControl setCurrentPageIndicatorTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
        [tidesPageControl setPageIndicatorTintColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
        [[cell contentView] addSubview:tidesPageControl];
        self.pageControl = tidesPageControl;
```

Here is my code which determines the current page I'm on:

```
(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)sender {
CGFloat pageWidth = sender.frame.size.width;

int page = floor((sender.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + 1;

NSLog(@"content offset x %f", sender.contentOffset.x);
NSLog(@"scroll view did scroll %d", page);

self.pageControl.currentPage = page;
```

}

The logs output the following when I scroll the UITableView up or down (whilst the page control is on the 2nd page):

```
2013-10-17 21:47:36.238 Vic [61180:a0b] content offset x 319.500000
2013-10-17 21:47:36.238 Vic [61180:a0b] page we are on 1
2013-10-17 21:47:36.254 Vic [61180:a0b] content offset x 320.000000
2013-10-17 21:47:36.254 Vic [61180:a0b] page we are on 1
2013-10-17 21:47:40.173 Vic [61180:a0b] content offset x 0.000000   <------scroll up here!
2013-10-17 21:47:40.173 Vic [61180:a0b] page we are on 0            <------ my problem!
2013-10-17 21:47:40.189 Vic [61180:a0b] content offset x 0.000000
```

Why would the contentoffset.x be resetting to zero?

Answer (score 7):

Worked it out; since I have a UIScrollView AND a UITableView together, and UITableView inherits from UIScrollView, both the table and scrollview are calling my scrollViewDidScroll method. So checking the class name of the sender parameter to scrollViewDidScroll fixes the problem- If its being called from the table (ie sender is a UITableView), do nothing. Otherwise if it's a UIScrollView, then check the page control etc.

Comment: sorry for the dump question. Can you please tell me were to check the sender inside viewDidScroll?

Comment: Hi Noel- check it at the very top of the method scrollViewDidScroll, use the sender param and if it's a tableview then just return.